# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline : COPY failed: stat .. no such file or directory

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have a VS 2019 solution containing three .Net Core 3.x Web Api projects that is checked into a Git repo.

I created a build pipeline In Azure DevOps via the wizard targeting my Azure AKS cluster.

The following pipeline YAML file was created..

[image]

While running this pipeline, I receive the following exception when it attempts to copy the Web API project files as noted in log below.

```
Step 6/38 : COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/API/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/API/"]

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder568816228/BoundedContexts/BC1/API/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj: no such file or directory
```

The file is is in the repository as viewed via Repository Viewer in Azure DevOps

[image]

This is the docker file that is failing in Azure DevOps pipeline...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/API/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/API/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventStore/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventStore.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventStore/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.RabbitMQ/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.RabbitMQ.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.RabbitMQ/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.Resilience/NextWare.Infrastructure.Resilience.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.Resilience/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/DomainExceptions/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.Domain.Exceptions.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/DomainExceptions/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/SharedKernel/NextWare.AppBuilder.SharedKernel.Domain.csproj", "BoundedContexts/SharedKernel/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.ServiceBus/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.ServiceBus.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.ServiceBus/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/Application/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.Application.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/Application/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/Infrastructure/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.Domain.Infrastructure.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/BC1/Domain/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.Domain.csproj", "BoundedContexts/BC1/Domain/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/SharedServices/Domain/NextWare.AppBuilder.SharedServices.Domain.csproj", "BoundedContexts/SharedServices/Domain/"]
COPY ["BoundedContexts/SharedServices/DomainExceptions/NextWare.AppBuilder.SharedServices.Domain.Exceptions.csproj", "BoundedContexts/SharedServices/DomainExceptions/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.WebHost/NextWare.Infrastructure.WebHost.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.WebHost/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.Kafka/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.Kafka.csproj", "Infrastructure/NextWare.Infrastructure.EventBus.Kafka/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BoundedContexts/BC1/API/NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BoundedContexts/BC1/API"
RUN dotnet build "NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NextWare.AppBuilder.BC1.API.dll"]
```

I am able to build and run this solution within Docker for Windows on my local dev env.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: WORKDIR refers to the active directory inside the container. All COPY and ADD commands will target this folder. There is no effect on the host filesystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [setting the `buildContext` input of the Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) at line 34 to `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)`. If you have multiple repos, try `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` (ref: [Azure Pipelines Predefined Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml))

When I'm having trouble with build context folder structure, sometimes I just throw a little [shell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops#example) at the beginning to `ls` some folders or run `tree` so I can see the structure.

Comment: Thank you bpdohall, by setting the buildContext to $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) it made it past that Copy error, built the image, and deployed it.

Comment: I am very new to Azure DevOps (like today) and what I was expecting to see was 3 images get created as there are 3 separate web API projects, each with their own docker files.  Instead only the first one was built and deployed.  Is there any examples on how to setup the pipeline YAML to deploy all web API projects in a given solution

Comment: @JohnKears - Azure DevOps doesn't really "know" that you have Docker build targets unless you define them in the pipeline. To add another project duplicate the "Docker" task ~ line 34 but point the new one at a different `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thank you again @bpdohall, you have helped me a lot! I have created a DDD DSL modeling tool that captures sub domains and generates a ASP.Net Core Web API per each bounded context. These each would require a docker image and container. Is there a best practice approach to automating the pipeline yaml instead of manually editing it for every project in a solution?

Comment: @JohnKears - You're welcome, glad I could help. You could check to see if all projects in the solution are represented in the pipeline on each commit, then insert a section into the `steps` array of the "Build" stage "Build" job that points to the unmatched Dockerfile. You'd need also have a step that commits the update back to the branch.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. My modeling solution is complimented with a Roslyn code generator CLI in which I will include a task to update the pipeline yaml file at the end of each code generation.  I keep track of changes so I should not only be able to handle the addition of new services but also removal and renaming of them.  This shouldn't be all that difficult to support.