# COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore in Azure DevOps YAML pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I have an existing Azure DevOps pipeline created using classic editor pipeline to dockerize      .NET web API and deploy to the Kubernetes using helm charts.

Now I am working on creating a brand new YAML pipeline for the same.
I got struck with one issue. COPY instruction failing to copy the solution file and nuget.config to the WORKDIR.

I have used dockercontext but no luck.
Also I have my Dockerfile and solution file present in Backend- Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API

**My project structure for backend looks like this**
Backend- Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API
Backend- Services/Services/LalithaInstitue/LalithaInstitue.API

**Error Message:**
Step 7/30 : COPY ["Backend-Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API/MaheshManagement.API.csproj", "Backend-Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Backend-Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API/MaheshManagement.API.csproj: file does not exist
##[error]COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Backend-Services/Services/MaheshInstitue/MaheshInstitue.API/MaheshManagement.API.csproj: file does not exist
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

Also I am using self hosted agent for this implementation

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me to resolve the issue
[Azure DevOps Build Pipeline : COPY failed: stat .. no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856563/azure-devops-build-pipeline-copy-failed-stat-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

Try setting the buildContext input of the Docker task at line 34 to $(Build.Repository.LocalPath). If you have multiple repos, try $(Pipeline.Workspace) (ref: Azure Pipelines Predefined Variables)

When I'm having trouble with build context folder structure, sometimes I just throw a little shell script at the beginning to ls some folders or run tree so I can see the structure.